# RTC on STM32 doesn't start running, except when a breakpoint is active

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, low-power, rtc, stm32cubeide

I use:

- STM32L071K8U3
- Segger JLink + Segger Ozone + SWD with 4 MHz
- Cube Ide
- External LSE or internal LSE, same problem.

I wrote firmware that displays the time using the RTC. To update the display, I check if the time has changed, like this:

```
if (hrtc.Instance->TR != trBefore) {
  trBefore = hrtc.Instance->TR;
  ...
}
```

Or like this (more portable):

```
if (HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc, &rtcTime, RTC_FORMAT_BCD) != HAL_OK) {
  Error_Handler();
}
      
if (rtcTime.Seconds != secondsBefore) {
  secondsBefore = rtcTime.Seconds;
  ...
}
```

Everything works fine, except that the time is not changing.

Using the debugger, I found that the RTC registers don't change.

If I use breakpoints and step into this `HAL_RTC_GetTime` and observe the RTC registers,
then they change, and as a consequence, my clock display is updated with the new time value.

Maybe related to this: if I use Cube Ide Eclipse CDT debugger instead of Segger Ozone, I sometimes get an error message "interrupt failed". I suspect this is related; something weird is going on here.

Also, if I completely disconnect the debugger, and flash the firmware with JFlash, everything works properly, except the time is not advancing on my display.

Comment: The question is: How to get the RTC running correctly.

Comment: Does your program behave differently if you rebuild with all compiler optimizations disabled?  If so then perhaps some of your memory mapped registers or variables should be declared volatile.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is [here](http://www.efton.sk/STM32/gotcha/g6.html).

In short, RTC time/date registers have to be read all of them (SSR, TR, DR), and twice.

Otherwise a lock mechanism, which is supposed to prevent data inconsistency, disconnects the registers from the APB bus, so the clock appears not to be running.